# openGl How to disable the GL_CLIP_DISTANCE?

Tags: c++, opengl

I met problems that GL_CLIP_DISTANCE is working without glEnable() 
in the vertex shader I had

```
#version 330 core
layout(location=0) in vec3 p;
layout(location=2) in vec2 coord;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 proj;

uniform vec4 plane;
out vec2 Coord;

void main(){
  gl_Position=proj*view*model*vec4(p,1.0f);
  vec4 vsPos = model * vec4(p,1.0f);
  gl_ClipDistance[0]=dot(plane,vsPos);
  Coord=coord;
}
```

in the main loop I had setclipPlane defined value externally

```
While(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)){
  //...do something
  shader.setClipPlane("plane",vec4(0,deltaY,deltaZ,deltaDep));  
  glBindVertexArray(VAO);
  //glEnable(GL_CLIP_DISTANCE0);
      glm::quat q = glm::quat(glm::vec3(glm::radians(0.0f),glm::radians(0.0f),glm::radians(0.0f)));
      glm::mat4 model=glm::toMat4(q);
      model = glm::translate(model,cubePositions[i]);
      shader.applyMatrix("model",model);
      glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES,0,36);
  //glDisable(GL_CLIP_DISTANCE0);
  glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

glIsEnable(GL_CLIP_DISTANCE0) returns false when I comment out the glEnable().
The setClipPlane is just find uniform and assign value. but the clip plane still affect in my main loop, any help?

Comment: Sounds like a driver snafu.  Edit in a [mcve].  Intel silicon on Windows?

Comment: Im using windows with the intel integrated graphics. Is that causing the problem?

Comment: Historically Intel's OpenGL drivers haven't been the best on the conformance front, especially on the less-trodden corners of the spec.  I could see them just kinda...forgetting to hook up the `glEnable()` state up.  You *might* try enabling/disabling it before the shader program bind, possibly even before you compile/link the shader.  That's getting into pretty far-out non-conformance though.  Make sure your driver is up-to-date & keep working on that MCVE.

Comment: Yes, it wouldn't shock me that a feature like this could be broken in a driver. It seems quite unusual to have a shader that writes to `gl_ClipDistance[]`, but then disables clipping. Of course it *should* work, but the condition might not be sufficiently covered in regression tests. As a workaround, you can of course have a separate shader without clipping for the case where you don't want to clip. But if you can reproduce it with a single example, definitely file a bug with the vendor. Just for the heck of it, I would also try it with a GPU from a different vendor.

Comment: Is there a way I can write clipPlane outside the shader? I've tried using `glClipPlane(GL_CLIP_DISNTANCE0,double[])` but it did not work either. Or Can I use stencil to achieve the same result for just showing the cross section of objects?

Comment: `glClipPlane (...)` is definitely not how you set clipping distances. Clip planes take actual plane equations (normal + distance). Clip distances are a simplification that was added when geometry shaders were. Incidentally, your original question doesn't discuss anything about wanting to draw cross sections... we don't really know what you're trying to do here.

Comment: I was intend to do a cross section through a solid cube and collect all the intersect data on the section. I want to be able to toggle the clip plane on and off .But the main problem is the clipPlane is not working as expected